# How to get openlayers 3 zoom control to show up on right side?

Tags: openlayers-3

By default the openlayers 3 zoom controls are on the top left. How can I move it to the top right? The API appears to return a broken link when going into options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using casading style sheets.

```
.ol-zoom {
   right: 8px
}
```

Comment: Me too. "left: unset;" actually. Please edit your answer.

Comment: Also had to use *left: auto* as *unset* would not work in IE 11.

Answer (score 16):

Use cascading style sheets. You need to unset the previous "left" value.

```
  .ol-zoom {
     left: unset;
     right: 8px;
  }
```

Comment: *unset* leads to a strange effect in IE 11. I would rather use *auto*.

Comment: use left: auto instead of left: unset, works fine in IE11